# How do I replace this with a variable?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I was trying to create a function in c++ which would slowly type in each letter into the console like a video game.
now the problem i'm having is creating a string variable which would replace the job of "Hello World".

```
 void typein(//input goes here)

{

    char str[] = { "Hello World" //input goes here};

        int len = strlen(str);

    for (int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
            putchar(str[i]);
            Sleep(80);

    }
    Sleep(100);
    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Read ANY book about C++ before asking such questions.

Comment: [This is how I would write it in C++](http://pastebin.com/PEypU4Nz). What you have is very much C-like.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [*`std::string`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

```
void typein( const std::string& str )
{

   std::size_type len = str.size( );

   // ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pointer to the array of the str

```
void typein(char* str, int length){
    <your code goes here>
}
```